# dataset for hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata

Here I put the pig code . when I try to execute this code I see errors. I am unable to debug it. Can any one help me in debugging the code. PLease post the answer with their input and output result.

I would request people to answer the problem with their inputs and the output result. please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this dataset is multiple characters as a delimiter "::".  In pig you can't use multiple characters as a delimiter. To solve this problem you have 3 options

```
1. Use REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL build-in function(need to write regex for this input)
2. Write custom UDF
3. Replace the multiple character delimiter to single character delimiter(This is very simple).
```

I downloaded the dataset from this site **http://www.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/** and tried with option 3

```
    1. Go to your input folder /home/bigdata/sample/inputs/
    2. Run this sed command
        >> sed 's/::/$/g' movies.dat > Testmovies.dat
        >> sed 's/::/$/g' ratings.dat > Testratings.dat
        >> sed 's/::/$/g' users.dat > Testusers.dat
```

This will convert the multiple character delimiter '::' to single character delimiter '$'. I chosen '$' as  delimiter bcoz in all the three files '$' is not present.

```
    3. Now load the new input files(Testmovies.dat,Testratings.dat,Testusers.dat)  in the pig script using '$' as a delimiter
```

**Modified Pig Script:**

```
    -- filtering action and war movies
    A = LOAD 'Testmovies.dat' USING PigStorage('$')as (MOVIEID: chararray,TITLE:chararray,GENRE: chararray);
    B = filter A by ((GENRE matches '.*Action.*') AND (GENRE matches '.*War.*'));
    -- finding action and war movie ratings
    C = LOAD 'Testratings.dat' USING PigStorage('$')as (UserID: chararray, MovieID:chararray, Rating: int, Timestamp: chararray);
    D = JOIN B by $0, C by MovieID;
    -- calculating avg
    E = group D by $0;
    F = foreach E generate group as mvId,  AVG(D.Rating) as avgRating;
    -- finding max avg-rating
    G = group F ALL;
    H = FOREACH G GENERATE MAX(F.$1) AS avgMax;
    -- finding max avg-rated movie
    I = FILTER F BY (float)avgRating == (float)H.avgMax;
    -- filtering female users age between 20-30
    J = LOAD 'Testusers.dat' USING PigStorage('$') as (UserID: chararray, Gender: chararray, Age: int, Occupation: chararray, Zip: chararray);
    K = filter J by ((Gender == 'F') AND (Age >= 20 AND Age <= 30));
    L = foreach K generate UserID;
    -- finding filtered female users rated movies
    M = JOIN L by $0, C by UserID;
    -- finding filtered female users who rated highest rated action and war movies
    N = JOIN I by $0, M by $2;
    -- finding distinct female users
    O = foreach N generate $2 as User;
    Q1 = Distinct O;
    DUMP Q1;

    Sample Output:
    (5763)
    (5785)
    (5805)
    (5808)
    (5812)
    (5825)
    (5832)
    (5852)
    (5869)
    (5878)
    (5920)
    (5955)
    (5972)
    (5974)
    (6009)
    (6036)
```

Comment: I have tried to execute the above code with your suggestions in pig local mode. But I am not getting output, getting the following errors.

Comment: Input(s):
Successfully read 2000360 records from: "/home/bigdata/movies/Testratings.dat"
Successfully read 6040 records from: "/home/bigdata/movies/Testusers.dat"
Successfully read 58 records from: "/home/bigdata/movies/Testratings.dat"
Successfully read 3883 records from: "/home/bigdata/movies/Testmovies.dat"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "file:/tmp/temp1612815615/tmp206540224"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Comment: 2014-12-07 16:32:40,346 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Encountered Warning ACCESSING_NON_EXISTENT_FIELD 6009020 time(s).
2014-12-07 16:32:40,348 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
2014-12-07 16:32:40,355 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized

Comment: 2014-12-07 16:32:40,359 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2014-12-07 16:32:40,359 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1